# Im Having Internet Connectivity issues on most of my applications. 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, steam, minecraft

I seem to be having troubles with most of my programs connecting to the internet, and I'm not sure what I can do at this point.

It started with me trying to download minecraft, I have a valid account and it logs in just fine on the website. So I go to login with the minecraft launcher downloaded from the website and I'm getting an error:

Sorry! Make sure you are online and try again

So I did some searching around and someone had a solution of downloading 'MultiMC' a Third party Installer, and it should work better.

After downloading that, the program had issues of it's own with connecting to the internet to download minecraft. So I thought this must be an isolated problem with minecraft. Yet then I remembered that my Steam Client *Also* has issues, and gives a 'Could not connect to steam network' error nine times out of ten, and barely ever logs in successfully.

So some of my programs are working Perfectly: Spotify, firefox, Discord.
And Some of them have a few issues connecting: Steam, Weather, software centre.
And some just dont connect, even after many restarts: Minecraft, MultiMC.

Seeing how this issue is spread across multiple programs I've deemed it as an issue with my own system. I know for a fact that my network is not to blame.

I don't think there are any Firewalls turned on, but I may be wrong, this is a pretty new install though.

Here is my Hardware Via 'sudo lshw': https://pastebin.com/4eZmhDRR

Comment: Look at (don't post in your Question, don't respond in comments) `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`.

Comment: It's been a few days, and i still cant find _Anything_ that has helped my issue, and this command didn't bring be anywhere either, no error messages or anything. Just a bunch of internet issues in my programs. and the system started hanging sometimes now, it just seems to be getting worse and I can't find anything to fix it.